# Masking input AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, validation, input, masking

I need to create mask for input field where user can input symbols only like in template: "01ABC2345-67-89" - two digits, then three chars, then four digits, then "-"(or if he input digit, "-" add automatically), then two digits, "-" and again two digits.
There is my code - my mask filter only numbers. Ho to create regexp for my objective?

html:

```
<html ng-app="app">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>serialNumber mask</title>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.6/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="main.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body ng-controller="myCtrl">
        <input type="text" id="serialNumber" ng-model="model.serialNumber">
        <br>
        <label for="serialNumber">format: 01ABC2345-67-89</label>
        <br><br>
{{model.serialNumber}}
    </body>
</html>
```

and js:

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('myCtrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.model = {};
    $scope.$watch('model.serialNumber', function (newValue, oldValue) {
        console.log('newValue', newValue);
        var regex = new RegExp('^\\d+$');
        if (newValue) {
            if (!regex.test(newValue)) {
                $scope.model.serialNumber = oldValue;
            }
        }

    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this example out. The only thing it does't do it delete properly. I figured you can solve this issue on your own though.

The Regex used matches any digit `[0-9]` twice, then looks for any character `[A-Z]` three times, then any number `[0-9]` four times, then a `-` character, then any digit `[0-9]` two times, then another `-` character. Finally any digit `[0-9]` two time again. `^` Means the sequence begins with, and `$` means it ends with. So essentially, any line that beings and ends with that Regex.

```
^[0-9]{2}[A-Z]{3}[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}$
```

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.model = {};

  $scope.checkForChanges = function() {
    var regex = new RegExp('^[0-9]{2}[A-Z]{3}[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}$');
    var len = $scope.model.serialNumber.length;
    if (len == 9 | len == 12) {
      $scope.model.serialNumber += "-";
    }
    if (regex.test($scope.model.serialNumber)) {
      console.log("matches");
      $scope.isMatch = "Regex match!";
    } else {
      $scope.isMatch = "Regex mismatch!";
    }

  }

  $scope.clear = function() {
    $scope.model.serialNumber = "";
  }
});
```

```html
<html ng-app="app">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>serialNumber mask</title>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="myCtrl"> <input type="text" id="serialNumber" ng-model="model.serialNumber" ng-change="checkForChanges()"> <br> <label for="serialNumber">format: 01ABC2345-67-89</label> <br>
  <button ng-click="clear()">Clear</button>
  <br> {{model.serialNumber}} </body>
<div>{{isMatch}}</div>

</html>
```

Comment: @KumarSrivastava Copy and paste `01ABC2345-67-89` inside the test box. Make sure the letters are capitalized and it matches the format you gave as an example.

Comment: I can input random text in this input like "Qwerty". It's wrong. I need a solution where user can input symbols only like in template.

Comment: @KumarSrivastava You can't block input from the keyboard to only allow the format to pass through. Validation is used when you only want to execute on the given format. Nobody can make the user not enter in `Qwerty`. But you can definitely stop the user from executing `Qwerty` by validating the input. If the validation doesn't work then we just won't execute.